# Как достать текст группы из совпадения?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Пытаюсь вот так: https://ideone.com/yjKItY

```
import re

s = '#100001000100#'
match = re.search('#((100+)+)#', s, re.IGNORECASE)
print(match.groups(1))
```

Получается `('100001000100', '100')`, а мне надо только `100001000100`.

Comment: [вот еще один вариант парсинга всех групп из строки](https://ideone.com/zRT5dU)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо использовать не `groups`, а `group`: https://ideone.com/7IPXLb

```
import re

s = '#100001000100#'
match = re.search('#((100+)+)#', s, re.IGNORECASE)
print(match.group(1))
```

```
100001000100
```

Answer (score 0):

Вхождение группы можно достать просто через квадратные скобки: https://ideone.com/nPYBlt

```
import re

s = '#100001000100#'
match = re.search('#((100+)+)#', s, re.IGNORECASE)
print(match[1])
```