# Почему такая разница при выводе строки, после обработки Regex?

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

При отображении объекта, видно что Regex отработал верно, но когда я пытаюсь достать результат, отображается необработанный текст. Почему?

```
import re

url = 'https://market.yandex.ru/catalog/57367/filters?text=%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0&onstock=0&deliveryincluded=0&local-offers-first=0'
url = re.search('(?<=text=).+&', url)
print(url)  
#<re.Match object; span=(52, 151), match='%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%\>
print(url[0])     
#D0%BE%D1%82%20%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0&onstock=0&deliveryincluded=0&
```

Comment: Единственное, что странно в этом выводе - это потерявшийся знак процента перед `D0`, всё остальное выглядит совершенно верно.

Comment: Как в итоге можно получить этот результат? "%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%"

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как достать текст группы из совпадения?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/850304/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%bf%d1%8b-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Answer (score 0):

Значение параметра с именем `text` можно получить любым из следующих способов: https://ideone.com/pIe4JB

```
import re

url = input()

print(re.search('(?<=[?&]text=)[^&#]*', url)[0])
print(re.search('[?&]text=([^&#]*)', url)[1])
print(re.search('[?&]text=([^&#]*)', url).group(1))

print(re.search('^[^?#]+(?=\?)[^#]*[?&]text=([^&#]*)', url)[1])
```

В общем случае последний вариант самый правильный.

Comment: Я помозговал и пришёл к этому: "re.findall('(?<=text=)[^&]+', url)"